# Filter and Search

Tags: filters, search, sort, code

I am working on my site which is a WordPress based site. It is a sweepstakes site well winprizesonline.com is the site which inspired me most. Now I want a dynamic search like that site on my site but I have no idea how and where to add code.

Like here; http://www.winprizesonline.com/new/contests/ you can see the 3 search boxs, Sort By:, Entry:, Next Entry: I want same search box with same function of filtering and search. Anyone know its code and can tell me where to put it on my site. I am using DirectoryPress theme for my site. Please I need its answer urgently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's anything automatic for what you're looking for, no. I built a similar functionality for sorting products with dimensions, but this was all custom as I did not find anything that suited my needs. You'd need to look into [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) using `$_GET` requests.

Answer (score 0):

[Query Multiple Taxonomies](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/) can do this for you. You'd need to organize your posts into taxonomies and then use the widget to display the UI for filtering.